# how to achieve high detailed particles like pixie dust

Tags: particles

I was trying to work with particles to make them look like in these photos, but I only got them to look like the 4th photo

[image]

[image]

[image]

this is what I made:

[image]

I am quite a beginner with complex particles.
Thanks!

Comment: Well, at least in the third image you can see there is depth of field causing a Bokeh effect which you have not in yours... which would be a camera setting. Then there are not only particles but some haze/mist/smoke effect which you either have to do with a smoke simulation or fake with some texture effects.